# document.writeln doesn't write to a new line

Tags: javascript

I was just writing some simple code and I noticed that using document.writeln doesn't write to a new line, permit me to demonstrate...

```
    // this is my JSON object
var myObject = {
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName": "Smith",
 "age": 25,
 "address": [{
    "Address1": "11 My Street",
    "Address2" : "Nice Area",
    "Town" : "Nice Town",
    "PCode" : "P05T 0DE"
    }]
 }

document.writeln(myObject.firstName);
document.writeln(myObject.address[0].Address1);
```

now this outputs the following....

> John 11 My Street

It's all on one line? If I used document.write() I'd expect this? It's happening in both IE & Firefox. Obviously I could add `+ "<br/>"` or `+ "\n"` but I shouldn't need to do that?

Am I being stupid?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HTML layout engines fold all whitespace to a single space. Of *course* you need `<br />` or some other mechanism that HTML uses for putting things on separate lines.

Answer (score 11):

[`document.writeln`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/writeln) does this:

> Writes a string of text followed by a newline character to a document.

But whitespace is collapsed and converted to a single space when rendering HTML so your newline does nothing inside the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

It just appears to be all on one line. Do this --

```
document.write('<pre>');
document.writeln(myObject.firstName);
document.writeln(myObject.address[0].Address1);
```

and you'll see.

Comment: I was having trouble with our page printing sub sections in chrome. This got the html to show in the preview. No idea why, but it worked.

Answer (score 3):

view the source of the page to see how the browser puts each line on a line-
but if you want to see a newline in the html, yes, put a `'<br>'` between them.

Answer (score 1):

What you are outputting is being interpreted as HTML and you have to output the formatting tags to get it to look the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that the source code of the page would have it on two lines, but the browser will condense it to one line since it condenses all white space to a single space. So in the browser, it displays it on one line.

As you said, you need to add a BR element to get it displayed on two lines.

Answer (score 1):

`document.writeln()` *does* append a `\n` to each line. However, in HTML whitespace is all displayed as a single space; you'll need to add `<br>` or `<p>` tags yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To use document.write() or document.writeln() to get some type of a list or new text lines in an HTML document:

```
    var somevar = "foo";
    for(i=1;i<4;i++){
    document.write(i+". "+somevar+"<br>");
    }
```

This will output:

1. foo
2. foo
3. foo

Comment: Why are you answering on a question asked a year ago with an accepted answer already?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put JavaScript code in `<pre>`tag.

```
<body>
     <pre>
          <script src="your_javascript.js"></script>
     </pre>
</body>
```